# How does `instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Entity a)` work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I am trying to create a simple JSON API client, and have found one [implemented for Twitter in Haskell](https://github.com/himura/twitter-types). My current goal is outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694619/haskell-way-of-modeling-a-type-with-dynamic-json-fields), but the same thing is demonstrated below.

In that Twitter/Haskell API code, there is this snippet:

[https://github.com/himura/twitter-types/blob/master/Web/Twitter/Types.hs#L577-L587](https://github.com/himura/twitter-types/blob/c8f7b01f6d3a19b517cef83e2f7ae8756c35b497/Web/Twitter/Types.hs#L577-L587)

```
type EntityIndices = [Int]

data Entity a = Entity {
  entityBody :: a,                -- ^ The detail information of the specific entity types (HashTag, URL, User)
  entityIndices :: EntityIndices, -- ^ The character positions the Entity was extracted from
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Entity a) where
  parseJSON v@(Object o) = Entity <$> parseJSON v
                                  <*> o .: "indices"
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

What is happening here?

First, from my understanding, That `data` block is a [Generalized Algebraic Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859200/real-world-use-of-gadt), because you are passing a parameter into the type `data Entity a`, and that `a` is being used in `entityBody :: a`.

Second, how do you instantiate that `Entity` generalized algebraic data type?

Finally, what is happening here?

```
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Entity a) where
```

What does that `=>` mean?

I can break this into multiple questions if that helps, but it all seems sorta interconnected.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but note that the ` ` syntax doesn't work in titles - it's taken and appears as a literal.

Comment: FYI, that’s an algebraic data type, but it isn’t a *generalized* algebraic data type.

Comment: `=>` reads like implication. `instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Entity a) where` means, "given an instance FromJSON a, we can constructor an instance FromJSON (Entity a)", or "the existence of FromJSON a implies the existence of FromJSON (Entity a)".

Answer (score 3):

The definition for `Entity`

```
data Entity a = Entity {
  entityBody :: a,                -- ^ The detail information of the specific entity types (HashTag, URL, User)
  entityIndices :: EntityIndices, -- ^ The character positions the Entity was extracted from
} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

`a` can be of any type. There are no restrictions. The instance for `FromJSON` for `Entity` puts a restraint on the type of `a`. It is saying this instance of `FromJSON` for `Entity` the `a` type must also have an instance of `FromJSON` defined.

For example the `show` typeclass.

```
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

In order to call the `show` function the argument passed in `a` must have an instance of `Show`. The `=>` just separates the typeclass constraints for the type definition.

So back to the `FromJSON`. If you define your own data type.

```
data Person = Person { name :: String }
```

And write the code

```
let e = eitherDecode data :: Either String (Entity Person)
```

It won't compile because you haven't defined an instance of `FromJSON` for `Person`. If you create the instance then it will work.

```
instance FromJSON Person where
    parseJSON (Object o) = Person <$> o .: "name"
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```